# Populating MySQL database with python randomly 'freezing'

Tags: python, mysql, database, pandas, sqlalchemy

My script connects to a MySQL database using sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@ip:port/dbName")
```

Then reads in txt files using pandas read_csv function and the dataframe is used to create a new table in the database using:

```
df.to_sql(tableName, con=engine, flavor='mysql', schema=None, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Script works perfectly fine, except randomly it seems to get stuck on the previous statement i.e. writing to the database. By random I mean that this is not file specific and so for example does not simply take longer to upload larger files. If I restart it, the file on which it was previously 'frozen' is uploaded instantly, but then it freezes again say 12 files afterwards or 1 file afterwards (very random). The table it 'freezes' on is actually fully uploaded (when I check the database, its all there) so it seems to freeze from going to the next statement. (No errors are thrown; script seems to be running normally except nothing happens). Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

After enabling debugging, when freezing it seems to do all the tasks (hence why the table shows up even in the database) i.e.

```
2016-03-16 03:16:19,720 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2016-03-16 03:16:19,806 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2016-03-16 03:16:19,935 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2016-03-16 03:16:20,015 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO `tableName` COLUMNS (***shortened this***)
2016-03-16 03:16:21,482 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2016-03-16 03:16:21,686 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `dbName`
2016-03-16 03:16:21,686 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
```

it simply does not continue to go on to the next command which is next iteration (again this is not always the case; seems to stop after about 1-3 tables now)

Comment: Is it a remote database? Are you sure you have internet when it gets stuck like that?

Comment: Yes it is a remote database. 100% positive network is not dropping. Turning echo to true, basically 'freezes' here:

`code`
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO etc etc etc...
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ({'list goes here'})
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `dbname`
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
`code`

Answer (score 0):

It could be Python garbage collection. Check in your system activity monitor. GC should show up as the Python process using lots of CPU.

The [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) library can help you troubleshooting and tuning the garbage collector.

Comment: CPU is hardly used and GC process is not listed. Using pycharm as an IDE and it uses 1.3% CPU when the script 'freezes'.